# Google OAuth2: "Error: No access, refresh token or API key is set" when trying to access Google Drive API

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to simply listing files in my google drive. I am following the nodeJS tutorial for this: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs

I'm trying to understand where I went wrong. The code I have is exactly the same as in the tutorial.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
      console.log('Files:');
      files.map((file) => {
        console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No files found.');
    }
  });
}
```

Some other things to note:

- I installed the google drive api library with `yarn add googleapis@39`, so I am using v39 of the api.
- I made my credentials by following the instructions in the tutorial, and downloading the file that was generated
- Ive debugged and confirmed that the auth object in listFiles is defined and the credentials exist

Any ideas would be great. I am also running node 16.13.1 and yarn 1.22.10 if that helps at all

Comment: The whole log output is missing ...and the API response might be accurate.

Comment: The log output was just `The API returned an error: Error: No access, refresh token or API key is set.`

Comment: After looking into the stack dump, I found that an error was being thrown at line 274 in `google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js`. Looks like it fails when it checks for `!thisCreds.access_token && !thisCreds.refresh_token && !this.apiKey`. This is really weird, because my tokens are being stored in `thisCreds.tokens.access_token, thisCreds.tokens.refresh_token`, etc. As you can see in the code above, I got this token from `google.auth.OAuth2`'s `getToken` function. I wonder if this is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix was to change

```
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
```

to

```
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      token = token.tokens;
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
```

The tokens themselves are stored in `tokens`. google oauth2 looks for the access token in the root of the credentials object, not in the tokens object where it is stored, so it's necessary to just store the tokens.

I have no idea why this wasn't included in the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you so much. I kept getting the error **No access, refresh token or API key is set.** I kept wondering why any of them weren't set. It was due to this problem ie. looking in wrong place.